# Activate (Start) Facebook Video Calling

Tags: facebook

How do I start using Facebook video calling?
I do not see it in the chat sidebar options.
Also I do not see the option on the profile pages of my friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Login to Facebook.
2. Go here: https://www.facebook.com/videocalling
3. Click on the **Get Started** button.
4. Click on a contact from your friends list.
5. You will see a new button in the upper right corner of the chat window.
   [image]

Depending on your OS, you might need/not need to install something.

> **Installation Flows for Each Browser and OS**
>   To make installation as easy as possible, we specifically customized the installation flow for each OS and browser combination. For instance, on Mac browsers with Java enabled, the installer is hosted entirely within the browser so that no additional clicks are required. We use a small bootstrap EXE in Windows browsers to minimize the initial download time and to manage installation permissions as seamlessly as possible.

From here: https://www.facebook.com/notes/philip-su/building-video-calling/10150229123673920

Comment: Also, both you and your friend have to currently be "online for chat" in order for the call button to appear at the top of their profile.

Answer (score 3):

Can't use Facebook at work, but I found this at [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5818620/facebook-just-got-video-calling-and-group-chat):

1. Go to [the video calling page](https://www.facebook.com/videocalling) and enable video chat
2. Pick a friend to video chat with and open the chat window
3. Click the video call icon on the top right of the chat window
4. Wait while the plugin installs
5. Chat!